# Is there a way to force Uncaught Cannot tween a null target to provide a line number or stack trace?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, gsap

Debugging the error `Uncaught Cannot tween a null target` has always infuriated me in chrome, because the console does not provide the offending Tween call. Especially on projects where several things are supposed to be animating at once.

Answer (score 0):

If your developer tools are open before the warning is thrown, you should be able to click on the warning to see the stack trace:
[image]

You can then click on the file name to jump to the offending line.

Side note: if you want to hide these warnings, you can use GSAP's config:

```
gsap.config({nullTargetWarn: false});
```